# Как упаковать nodejs файл в .exe?

Tags: javascript, node.js

У меня есть парсер логов написанный на nodejs который принимает несколько аргументов, файл для чтения и файл для записи. Что лучше всего использовать для упаковки моего кода в исполняемый файл виндовс?
Я пробовал [nexe](https://github.com/nexe/nexe) но дальше бинарника дело не дошло. Подскажите, расскажите, кто как это делает.

Comment: если нет особых требований к приложению то можно упаковать в electron https://www.electronjs.org/

Comment: можно запаковать как ресурс

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Модуль PKG: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg

```
npm install -g pkg
pkg main.js
```

Где main.js - ваш скрипт.

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте вот эту статью "How to create an executable (.exe) file from JavaScript code (using Node.js)":
https://medium.com/jspoint/how-to-create-an-executable-exe-file-from-javascript-code-using-node-js-45154ba4de20